# Why is the conversion from ulong to DateTime returning 0?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I'm trying to convert `ULONG to DateTime` and as `DateTime` accepts Ticks as param which are LONG, here's how I do it.

```
ulong time = 12354;
new DateTime((long)time).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

The result of this is `00:00:00`.

I don't understand the result, am I doing something wrong?

P.S. `i.Time` is not `0`, I checked multiple times.

Comment: What is `i.time` exactly then? Can you debug your code and tell us?

Comment: i.Time is "Time Left", ULONG.

Comment: What if the ticks you provided point to some day at midnight exactly ?

Comment: I've checked multiple times at different items and all were the same which doesn't make sense.

Comment: To get any meaningful value from a DateTime constructed by Ticks you need a value of at least 10000000 for the constructor

Comment: Try 123412345123455

Comment: @Steve The API is soloely returning that short ulong as displayed. How could that be converted to "Time Left" as it describes then? Thanks

Comment: And what represent that value? If these are Ticks then you have a very, very small time value. A tick is100 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 4):

Citing [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to a specified number of ticks.
>
> **ticks**
>
> Type: System.Int64
>
> A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

This is *100 nanoseconds* which is a super small time unit. So unless your number is larger than 10000000, you don’t even get *a single second*:

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime((long)10000000).ToString());
// 01.01.0001 00:00:01
```

So you should really think about what your “time left” (`i.Time`) value is supposed to mean? Is this really time in the unit of 100 nanoseconds? Very likely not. It’s probably more about seconds or something completely different.

Btw. if the number you have does not actually represent a *moment in time*, you should not use `DateTime`. You should use [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instead. Its `long` constructor has the same behavior though, but you can use one of the handy static functions to create a time span with the correct unit:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
// 00:16:40
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now. It's most probably "seconds" left which is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @J.Doe Yeah, that sounds likely. You should really use a `TimeSpan` anway; I have added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because a tick is 100 nanoseconds, and so 12354 ticks is only 1235400 nanoseconds which is only .0012354 seconds. So your datetime is .0012354 seconds after midnight on 1 Jan in the year one.